# How does Ransomware use vssadmin.exe with admin privileges

Tags: ransomware

I am doing some research about Ransomware and their methods. In many articles they write that the ransomware performs vssadmin.exe to delete shadow copys. And I found following Information about how they bypass the problem that admin privileges are needed:

> "As this program (vssadmin.exe) requires Administrative privileges to run, some ransomware will inject themselves into processes that are running as an Administrator in order to avoid a UAC prompt from being displayed."

My question is, how do they inject themselves into those processes? Any Links or Information about this would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many process injection techniques, there is no standard way used in all ransomware.

Some of these techniques:

- Classic Dll Injection Via Createremotethread And Loadlibrary.
- Portable Executable Injection (Pe Injection) Process Hollowing (A.K.A
  Process Replacement And Runpe)
- Thread Execution Hijacking (A.K.A    Suspend, Inject, And Resume
  (Sir))
- Hook Injection Via Setwindowshookex
- Injection And Persistence Via Registry Modificatio (E.G.
  Appinit_Dlls, Appcertdlls, Ifeo)
- Apc Injection And Atombombing
- Extra Window Memory Injection (Ewmi) Via Setwindowlong
- Injection    Using Shims Iat Hooking And Inline Hooking (A.K.A
  Userland Rootkits)

The following [link](https://www.endgame.com/blog/technical-blog/ten-process-injection-techniques-technical-survey-common-and-trending-process) describes all of the above techniques.